# PHP foreach loop - How to get the first, second and third result from all?

Tags: php, foreach

Right now i am working on a not very difficult php script, but i have really strange question.

How i can i point the first, secont and the third result to a variables ?

Here is my code example:

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `media` WHERE `item_id`=590');

$ids=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
$ids[]=$row->file;

    }
$ids=array_filter($ids);
foreach($ids as $id){
   $variable1 = $id[0];
   $variable2 = $id[1];
   $variable3 = $id[2];
 }
```

This is my code but it's not working as i want.

I want `$variable1` to point to the first printed result, `$variable2` to point to the second and etc...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just use the array, why create a new  variable for no gain

Comment: @Dagon so that it was a chance to use variables variables

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need the `foreach` loop. Would this work instead?

```
$variable1 = $ids[0];
$variable2 = $ids[1];
$variable3 = $ids[2];
```

Note, I've changed `$id[0]` to `$ids[0]` (added the "s") and removed the foreach loop.

This line is also redundant and can be safely removed.

```
$ids=array_filter($ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
list($variable1, $variable2, $variable3) = $ids;
```